# render multisampled and singlesampled texture inside framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to render into multisampled and singlesampled textures at the same time(drawcall).
Why do I want that? Because the multisampled Texture is using antialiasing while the singlesampled texture is used for colorpicking.
both textures (nRenderTargetTexture and nColorPickingTexture) have the same size.
If I run the code below, it fails at the GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE case.
Is it posible to render into multisampled and singlesampled textures at the same time?

Btw: I'm also using glGetError(), but it returns GL_NO_ERROR

```
// Enable multisampling
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

glGenFramebuffers(1, pFramebufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, *pFramebufferID);

// Create color render buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &nColorBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, nColorBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_RGBA8, nWidth, nHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, nColorBuffer);

// Create depth render buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &nDepthBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, nDepthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 4, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, nWidth, nHeight);

//Attach the multisampled textures
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, nDepthBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, nDepthBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, nRenderTargetTexture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, nColorPickingTexture, 0);
const GLenum draw_buffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};

glDrawBuffers(2, draw_buffers);

GLenum eFramebufferOk = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);

bool bResult = false;
switch (eFramebufferOk)
{
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
    {
        bResult = true;
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        DebugAssertOnce(CREATE_FRAME_BUFFER_FAILED);
    }
    break;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it posible to render into multisampled and singlesampled textures at the same time?

No. All images attached to a framebuffer must have the same sample count. Otherwise, you get `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE`.

Answer (score 0):

btw: to use antialiasing and picking with the same shader call, I use multisampled picking texture.
After I rendered my scene I do a 2nd renderstepp (2 triangles over the screen) and inside the fragmentshader I use:

```
texelFetch(pickingTexture,ivec2(position),0); //0 sample
```

it gives me back a not antialiasied picking texture.
I wrote this post because maybe someone is trying the same.